# Firestore not reconnecting after internet connection is lost

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Node.js backend which is connected to Firestore and listens for document inserts and updates. At times the internet goes down on server for few minutes but when the connections comes back, the connection to Firestore in not re-established.
I have tested the same on my local also by turning off the internet and getting the same issue.

- Node version: v12.14.0
- firebase-admin version: "^8.9.2"

But after restarting server things goes back to normal.

Comment: Is it only feature that is not working? What server it is?

Comment: I have primarily tested the feature of snapshot listener only. The backend is hosted on a linux docker. But I can reproduce same on my Mac.

Comment: Are there any exceptions on the server?